# How do i use different css files for different components React with same class names

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using scss and creating final css which is a combination of header footer etc components which remain the same across pages.

Say I have the below class and they are of the same names in two pages of mine say About us Component and Home page Component which different styles

```
.first-section {

}

import React from 'react'
import Header from './headers/Header'
import Footer from './footers/Footer'
import LeftDrawer from './LeftDrawer'

import '../../../../media/assets/css/landingpages/aboutus.css'

export default class AboutUs extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="page-container">
        <LeftDrawer></LeftDrawer> 
        <div class="page-container-inner" id="about-us">
          <Header></Header>

          <article class="first-section text-center">
          </article>
          <Footer></Footer>
          {/*<!-- /.page-container-inner -->*/}
        </div>
        {/*<!-- /.page-container -->*/}
      </div>      
    )
  }
}
```

**Similarily Home.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from './headers/Header'
import Footer from './footers/Footer'
import LeftDrawer from './LeftDrawer'

import '../../../../media/assets/css/landingpages/home.css'

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="page-container">
        <LeftDrawer></LeftDrawer> 
        <div class="page-container-inner" id="about-us">
          <Header></Header>

          <article class="first-section text-center">
          </article>
          <Footer></Footer>
          {/*<!-- /.page-container-inner -->*/}
        </div>
        {/*<!-- /.page-container -->*/}
      </div>      
    )
  }
}
```

How do I prevent these from clashing in React? cz they are of same names

Comment: So, you want to use `.first-section` class but they should have different styles for different pages?

Comment: @NirmalyaGhosh Yes I think we can manage it through webpack

Answer (score 1):

Use [CSS Modules](https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-3-react/).

A simple example, in your JS file, you could do:

```
import styles from './local.css';

<div className={styles.page-container}></div>
```

Then in your `local.css`, you need:

```
:local(.page-container) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

This `.page-container` style won't affect other ones (even if they are nested).

Yet I know this solution is not trivial. If you need a simpler implementation, you may consider using a library, such as [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components)

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled using CSS specificity.  Add a class to your `page-container` for each page.

`<div class="page-container home">`

and

`<div class="page-container about">`

Then in your CSS:

```
.first-section {
  /* your general .first-section styles */
}

.home .first-section {
  /* your home styles */
}

.about .first-section {
  /* your about styles */
}
```

The `.home .first-section` and `.about .first-section` blocks will not conflict and can override any general styles from `.first-section`.  Just make sure they are ordered that way in your css.

Answer (score 0):

I use Webpack to bundle React, and use the `css-loader` with css modules. When I import my css, I assign it to a variable: `import styles from '../../whatever.css';

Then, when I applying a class name, you use `styles.class` or `styles['class']`: `<article className={ styles['first-section'] }>...`. With css modules configured, this actually results in the class being something like `Home__first-section--kfoia8`, by pre-pending the component name, and appending a random hash. Check out the [css-loader docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader).